# Stop / prevent WordPress from updating permalinks of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, slug

I have a WordPress installation with a custom post type with a whole bunch of posts.

These posts all have a unique permalink which is being generated by FileMaker and synced with WordPress.

This works perfectly fine, however when I migrate the site onto another domain or refresh permalinks, all of these custom post slugs are updated with versions that are based on the post names.

Is there any way to FORCE WordPress to never update the slugs or permalinks of a custom post type?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. Something wrong with functions.php was changing the permalinks and creating this issue. Rolling back to a previous version of functions.php solved the problem. Infact, I didn't have to do anything other than replace that file and all the links appeared correctly again.

I then went through and redid all the changes I'd recently made to the functions file one by one and didn't encounter the issue. I may have accidentally deleted something or added something to functions.php by accident.